# Dependency between project licence and its dependencies' licenses

Tags: licensing

When I'm defining a license for my open software project, should I consider my project's dependencies and based on them define license for my project? 

Can anybody give me an example of license infringement in terms of dependencies licenses and my project license?

Comment: i was thinking of a contrived example where the license on a project is further restricted by its dependencies' licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm defining a license for my open software project, should I consider my project's dependencies and based on them define license for my project?

Yes, you should learn about which usage terms your dependencies have, so you know what you can do with the code.

If you have multiple dependencies, you need to check whether you can use them alltogether and under which conditions.

This can influence your own licence choice as well, as most software licenses explicitly operate that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could run into problems if, for example, you link against a GPL library but your license is not GPL compatible.  Here is the [FSF faq entry](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL) on the subject.

> If a library is released under the GPL (not the LGPL), does that mean that any software which uses it has to be under the GPL or a GPL-compatible license?
>
> Yes, because the software as it is actually run includes the library.

The same situation could arise if you combine any two incompatible licenses, depending on how they interact, but I think that will be the major pain point.